# Android Text to Speech embedded application

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech

I have a couple of basic questions about using Android + TTS which I can't seem to get definitively answered by searching:

This is an embedded commercial product to provide voice announcements for variable data. No UI as such other than a single pushbutton. At this stage I'm simply trying to decide whether to pursue Android or use one of the other TTS products on the market.

1. What are the licensing issues or costs? This will be lowish volumes, maybe 100's
2. Does TTS operate completely offline? (Assuming of course the relevant libraries are installed)

Apologies if this is not an appropriate forum - if there are better places to ask then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The official voice engine from google - [Google TTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) is completely offline and you would require your users to install a voice package beforehand.

Most of the current generation of android devices already have this package installed and it shouldn't be much of a problem.

To be on the safer side you can check at the start of your application launch and trigger an install in the user device if the package is not found.

But the major issue when using TTS is the quality of the voice provided by the engine,

Some of the main drawbacks include,

1. Voice is never satisfactory irrespective of any pitch level and speech rate you set using the inbuilt methods.
2. If you need a voice similar to the Runtastic app (which is by far the best voice assistant I found so far) you need to resort to a commercial voice engine or build your own.
3. Long running text needs to be separated by a comma to make sure there is a certain pause when the voice speaks else it would sound robotic.

The above are some of the issues I faced when using TTS and if you are able to live with the above points then the Google TTS is your best bet to implement in your app.

But since your app is mainly based on voice, I would recommend you to check if there are any other voice packages around since Google TTS is far from pleasant to hear and your users might find it very annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much you are expecting, but  my suggestion is try to use Google's text to speech. This is just a link, you need to pass the string and required language and this will return you a wav format file for the string which you sent. 
[Google TTS](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello).